# Problems trying to incorporate search into responsive menu

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm trying to make a responsive menu - I'm happy with the desktop version but I have messed up the mobile version of it.

On screens less than 600px how do I get the search bar to appear in the hamburger (ideally at the top with the search icon next to the textbox) instead of underneath that row?

(I'm also trying to make the menu bar sticky and replace the Home with a logo on under600px only, but one thing at a time ...)

Any help gratefully, gratefully, gratefully received.  Many thanks in advance!

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
html {
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

a:link {
  color: blue;
}

a:visited {
  color: blue;
}

a:hover {
  color: orange;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Reset padding and margin which gives us full width colour bars when required */
body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}


div.header {
padding: 20px;
font-size: 24px;
  color: white;
        background: #DD1100;
}

div.mainBlog{
padding: 20px;
font-size: 18px;
}

div.mainPanelMobile{
padding: 20px;
font-size: 18px;
}


div.mainPanel2{
padding: 20px;
background: yellow;
font-size: 18px;
}

div.footer {
padding: 20px;
font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
        background: #DD1100;
}

/* =============================================================== */

/* For mobile phones: any relevant code goes below */
/* if I want to make it invisible I need to add: */
/* position: absolute; */
/* left: -9999px; */
@media (max-width: 720px) {

div.mainPanel {
        background: white;
  padding: 20px;
}



}

/* =============================================================== */

/* For tablet computers: */
@media (min-width: 721px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

body{
        background: #FFF1E0;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 50px 20px 50px 20px;
}

div.wholeAreaIndex{
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        max-width:1400px;
        background: white;    
        margin: auto;
        box-shadow: 20px 20px 16px #111111;
}

div.wholeAreaPage{
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        max-width:1140px;
        background: white;    
        margin: auto;
        box-shadow: 20px 20px 16px #111111;
}

div.header {
  padding: 20px;
}

div.mainPanel {
        background: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

div.mainPanelMobile {
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
}

div.footer{
padding: 20px;
}

.sidebar {
    padding-left: 0px;
}

}

/* =============================================================== */

/* For desktop computers: */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {

body{
        background: #FFF1E0;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 50px 20px 50px 20px;
}

.left {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}

.right {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}

.sidebar {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

div.wholeAreaIndex{
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        max-width:1400px;
        background: white;    
        margin: auto;
        box-shadow: 20px 20px 16px #111111;
}

div.wholeAreaPage{
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        max-width:1140px;
        background: white;    
        margin: auto;
        box-shadow: 20px 20px 16px #111111;
}

div.header {
padding: 20px;
}

div.mainPanel {
        background: white;
padding: 20px;
}

div.mainPanelMobile {
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
}


div.footer{
padding: 20px;
}

}

/* =============================================================== */


/* This section is the CSS for the responsive menu: */

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #EEE;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .search-container {
  float: right;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
}

.topnav .search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.topnav .search-container button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}


/* When the screen is less than 600px wide, stack the links and the search field vertically instead of horizontally */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav input[type=text] {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px;
  }
  .topnav input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

.topnav .search-container {
  float: left;
}
.topnav .search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}



}


/* =============================================================== */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  </head>
    
  <body>
    
    <div class="wholeAreaIndex">
    
      <! –– header ––>
      <div class="header">
      Title
      </div>
    
      <! –– menu ––>
      <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="search-container">
          <form action="/action_page.php">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
            <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <! –– content  ––>
    
      <div class="mainPanel" style="background-color:yellow;">
        Hello! This is a header.
      </div>
    
      <div class="mainPanel">
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      </div>
    
      <! –– footer ––>
      <div class="footer">
      Footer
      </div>
    
    
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Always, Search bar should be display. See professional UI https://miro.medium.com/proxy/1*ILvNVFYka8q04RrsHTvkKA.png. Search bar should not be in the hamburger. It should be equivalent with  hamburger and home, Please check my answer to see result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 1st thing is that you are having 2 media queries with maxwidth
   600px. Just set one is enought.
2. Then I added in your 600px view in class: `.topnav a:not(:first-child)` like `.topnav a:not(:first-child), .topnav .search-container` like this, it will work like this other block
   over. LIke the search bar will be `display none` as well
3. Then I added `.topnav.responsive .search-container` to existing
   `.topnav.responsive a` to display. And added order to set search bar
   on the top

```
  .topnav.responsive .search-container{
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a:first-child, .topnav.responsive .search-container{
    order: -1;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .search-container form{
    display:flex;
  }
```

4. In order to make the `order`works, I also need to add display flex to container such as below

```
.topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
```

**DEMO**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
html {
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

a:link {
  color: blue;
}

a:visited {
  color: blue;
}

a:hover {
  color: orange;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Reset padding and margin which gives us full width colour bars when required */
body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}


div.header {
padding: 20px;
font-size: 24px;
  color: white;
        background: #DD1100;
}

div.mainBlog{
padding: 20px;
font-size: 18px;
}

div.mainPanelMobile{
padding: 20px;
font-size: 18px;
}


div.mainPanel2{
padding: 20px;
background: yellow;
font-size: 18px;
}

div.footer {
padding: 20px;
font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
        background: #DD1100;
}

/* =============================================================== */

/* For mobile phones: any relevant code goes below */
/* if I want to make it invisible I need to add: */
/* position: absolute; */
/* left: -9999px; */
@media (max-width: 720px) {

div.mainPanel {
        background: white;
  padding: 20px;
}



}

/* =============================================================== */

/* For tablet computers: */
@media (min-width: 721px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

body{
        background: #FFF1E0;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 50px 20px 50px 20px;
}

div.wholeAreaIndex{
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        max-width:1400px;
        background: white;    
        margin: auto;
        box-shadow: 20px 20px 16px #111111;
}

div.wholeAreaPage{
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        max-width:1140px;
        background: white;    
        margin: auto;
        box-shadow: 20px 20px 16px #111111;
}

div.header {
  padding: 20px;
}

div.mainPanel {
        background: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

div.mainPanelMobile {
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
}

div.footer{
padding: 20px;
}

.sidebar {
    padding-left: 0px;
}

}

/* =============================================================== */

/* For desktop computers: */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {

body{
        background: #FFF1E0;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 50px 20px 50px 20px;
}

.left {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}

.right {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}

.sidebar {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

div.wholeAreaIndex{
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        max-width:1400px;
        background: white;    
        margin: auto;
        box-shadow: 20px 20px 16px #111111;
}

div.wholeAreaPage{
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        max-width:1140px;
        background: white;    
        margin: auto;
        box-shadow: 20px 20px 16px #111111;
}

div.header {
padding: 20px;
}

div.mainPanel {
        background: white;
padding: 20px;
}

div.mainPanelMobile {
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
}


div.footer{
padding: 20px;
}

}

/* =============================================================== */


/* This section is the CSS for the responsive menu: */

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #EEE;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .search-container {
  float: right;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
}

.topnav .search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.topnav .search-container button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}


/* When the screen is less than 600px wide, stack the links and the search field vertically instead of horizontally */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav input[type=text] {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px;
  }
  .topnav input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child),
  .topnav .search-container {
    display: none;
    }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
  
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a,
  .topnav.responsive .search-container{
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a:first-child,
  .topnav.responsive .search-container{
    order: -1;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .search-container form{
    display:flex;
  }

.topnav .search-container {
  float: left;
}
.topnav .search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}



}


/* =============================================================== */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  </head>
    
  <body>
    
    <div class="wholeAreaIndex">
    
      <! –– header ––>
      <div class="header">
      Title
      </div>
    
      <! –– menu ––>
      <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="search-container">
          <form action="/action_page.php">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
            <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <! –– content  ––>
    
      <div class="mainPanel" style="background-color:yellow;">
        Hello! This is a header.
      </div>
    
      <div class="mainPanel">
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
      </div>
    
      <! –– footer ––>
      <div class="footer">
      Footer
      </div>
    
    
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @PaulGolder You welcome, please accept answer if it's fine by you. Have a good day

Comment: Hi, it is on left of my answer under the score I think

Answer (score 0):

I updated your snippet to fix search bar and sticky menu.

Same `@media` query is used multiple time. Please Try to put all the code together under a one media query `@media screen and (max-width: 600px)`, One media query is enough for 600px viewport. This is better for a clean and semantic code.

Always, Search bar should be display. See professional UI https://miro.medium.com/proxy/1*ILvNVFYka8q04RrsHTvkKA.png Search bar should not be in the hamburger. It should be equivalent with hamburger and home.

Please just update/add below CSS  to fix issues at end of `@media screen and (max-width: 600px)`.

You just need to update this CSS.

```
.topnav .search-container {
    position:absolute;
    left: 74px;
    top:0px;
}
.topnav {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 73px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
.wholeAreaIndex {
    padding-top: 124px;
}
.search-container form {
    display:flex;
}
.topnav .search-container button {
    float: right;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    background: #ddd;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.header {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

What I updated above CSS:-

**For Search :-**

Please set the element `.topnav .search-container` with position: absolute  is positioned relative/fixed to the positioned ancestor `.topnav`.

**Menu bar sticky :-**
Please set the element `.header` and .topnav with position: fixed to sticky menu and set `.wholeAreaIndex` by `padding-top:` accordingly.

Updated snippet :-

```css
  html {
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

a:link {
  color: blue;
}

a:visited {
  color: blue;
}

a:hover {
  color: orange;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Reset padding and margin which gives us full width colour bars when required */
body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}


div.header {
padding: 20px;
font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
        background: #DD1100;
}

div.mainBlog{
padding: 20px;
font-size: 18px;
}

div.mainPanelMobile{
padding: 20px;
font-size: 18px;
}


div.mainPanel2{
padding: 20px;
background: yellow;
font-size: 18px;
}

div.footer {
padding: 20px;
font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
        background: #DD1100;
}

/* =============================================================== */

/* For mobile phones: any relevant code goes below */
/* if I want to make it invisible I need to add: */
/* position: absolute; */
/* left: -9999px; */
@media (max-width: 720px) {

div.mainPanel {
        background: white;
    padding: 20px;
}



}

/* =============================================================== */

/* For tablet computers: */
@media (min-width: 721px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

body{
        background: #FFF1E0;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 50px 20px 50px 20px;
}

div.wholeAreaIndex{
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        max-width:1400px;
        background: white;    
        margin: auto;
        box-shadow: 20px 20px 16px #111111;
}

div.wholeAreaPage{
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        max-width:1140px;
        background: white;    
        margin: auto;
        box-shadow: 20px 20px 16px #111111;
}

div.header {
    padding: 20px;
}

div.mainPanel {
        background: white;
    padding: 20px;
}

div.mainPanelMobile {
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
}

div.footer{
padding: 20px;
}

.sidebar {
    padding-left: 0px;
}

}

/* =============================================================== */

/* For desktop computers: */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {

body{
        background: #FFF1E0;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 50px 20px 50px 20px;
}

.left {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}

.right {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}

.sidebar {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

div.wholeAreaIndex{
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        max-width:1400px;
        background: white;    
        margin: auto;
        box-shadow: 20px 20px 16px #111111;
}

div.wholeAreaPage{
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        max-width:1140px;
        background: white;    
        margin: auto;
        box-shadow: 20px 20px 16px #111111;
}

div.header {
padding: 20px;
}

div.mainPanel {
        background: white;
padding: 20px;
}

div.mainPanelMobile {
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
}


div.footer{
padding: 20px;
}

}

/* =============================================================== */


/* This section is the CSS for the responsive menu: */

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #EEE;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .search-container {
  float: right;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
}

.topnav .search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.topnav .search-container button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}


/* When the screen is less than 600px wide, stack the links and the search field vertically instead of horizontally */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav input[type=text] {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px;
  }
  .topnav input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

.topnav .search-container {

   position:absolute; left: 74px; top:0px;
}

.topnav {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 73px;
  width: 100%; left: 0;
}
.wholeAreaIndex{padding-top: 124px;}
.search-container form{display:flex;}
.topnav .search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.header{position: fixed;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
top: 0;}



}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<body>

<div class="wholeAreaIndex">

<! –– script for responsive menu ––>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>

<! –– header ––>
<div class="header">
Title
</div>

<! –– menu ––>
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
  <div class="search-container">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
      <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<! –– content  ––>

<div class="mainPanel" style="background-color:yellow;">
Hello! This is a header.
</div>

<div class="mainPanel">
Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
</div>

<! –– footer ––>
<div class="footer">
Footer
</div>


</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Your answer is not good because search bar should be in hamburger... as he said: "On screens less than 600px how do I get the search bar to appear in the hamburger "

Comment: Always, Search bar should be display. See professional UI ""https://miro.medium.com/proxy/1*ILvNVFYka8q04RrsHTvkKA.png"" Search bar should not be in the hamburger. It should be equivalent with hamburger and home.

Comment: This recommandation, I dont say that what you made is bad coding, I said that this is not what he is searching. But Thanks for the info

Comment: Thanks Priya Jain, looks nice but when I view it on my mobile phone I lose the hamburger

Comment: It can be z-index issue or if it is not. Please attach link that I can find actual solution for hamburger why it is hiding

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use same CSS layout(Fixable) you will be easy to responsive web page.
2. I used position relative to change position of same elements.
   An element with position: relative; is positioned relative to its normal position.
3. You can refer about flex layout using this reference.
   https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

    <style>
        html {
            font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
        }

        .clearfix:after {
            content: "";
            clear: both;
            display: table;
        }

        a:link {
            color: blue;
        }

        a:visited {
            color: blue;
        }

        a:hover {
            color: orange;
        }

        h2 {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 24px;
            display: inline;
            margin: 0;
        }

        /* Reset padding and margin which gives us full width colour bars when required */
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }


        div.header {
            padding: 20px;
            font-size: 24px;
            color: white;
            background: #DD1100;
        }

        div.mainBlog{
            padding: 20px;
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        div.mainPanelMobile{
            padding: 20px;
            font-size: 18px;
        }


        div.mainPanel2{
            padding: 20px;
            background: yellow;
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        div.footer {
            padding: 20px;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: white;
            background: #DD1100;
        }

        /* =============================================================== */

        /* For mobile phones: any relevant code goes below */
        /* if I want to make it invisible I need to add: */
        /* position: absolute; */
        /* left: -9999px; */
        @media (max-width: 720px) {

            div.mainPanel {
                background: white;
                padding: 20px;
            }



        }

        /* =============================================================== */

        /* For tablet computers: */
        @media (min-width: 721px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

            body{
                background: #FFF1E0;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 50px 20px 50px 20px;
            }

            div.wholeAreaIndex{
                padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
                max-width:1400px;
                background: white;
                margin: auto;
                box-shadow: 20px 20px 16px #111111;
            }

            div.wholeAreaPage{
                padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
                max-width:1140px;
                background: white;
                margin: auto;
                box-shadow: 20px 20px 16px #111111;
            }

            div.header {
                padding: 20px;
            }

            div.mainPanel {
                background: white;
                padding: 20px;
            }

            div.mainPanelMobile {
                position: absolute;
                left: -9999px;
            }

            div.footer{
                padding: 20px;
            }

            .sidebar {
                padding-left: 0px;
            }

        }

        /* =============================================================== */

        /* For desktop computers: */
        @media (min-width: 1200px) {

            body{
                background: #FFF1E0;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 50px 20px 50px 20px;
            }

            .left {
                width: 70%;
                float: left;
            }

            .right {
                width: 30%;
                float: left;
            }

            .sidebar {
                padding-left: 20px;
            }

            div.wholeAreaIndex{
                padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
                max-width:1400px;
                background: white;
                margin: auto;
                box-shadow: 20px 20px 16px #111111;
            }

            div.wholeAreaPage{
                padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
                max-width:1140px;
                background: white;
                margin: auto;
                box-shadow: 20px 20px 16px #111111;
            }

            div.header {
                padding: 20px;
            }

            div.mainPanel {
                background: white;
                padding: 20px;
            }

            div.mainPanelMobile {
                position: absolute;
                left: -9999px;
            }


            div.footer{
                padding: 20px;
            }

        }

        /* =============================================================== */


        /* This section is the CSS for the responsive menu: */

        .topnav {
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #EEE;
        }

        .topnav a {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            color: #000000;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 17px;
        }

        .topnav a:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
            color: black;
        }

        .topnav a.active {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
        }

        .topnav .search-container {
            float: right;
        }

        .topnav input[type=text] {
            padding: 6px;
            margin-top: 8px;
            font-size: 17px;
            border: none;
        }

        .topnav .search-container button {
            float: right;
            padding: 6px 10px;
            margin-top: 8px;
            margin-right: 16px;
            background: #ddd;
            font-size: 17px;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .topnav .search-container button:hover {
            background: #ccc;
        }


        /* When the screen is less than 600px wide, stack the links and the search field vertically instead of horizontally */
        @media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
            .topnav input[type=text] {
                float: none;
                display: block;
                text-align: left;
                width: 76vw;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 14px;
                position: relative;
                top: -1px;
                right: -3px;
            }
            .topnav .search-container {
                float: left;
                height: 53px;
            }
            .topnav input[type=text] {
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }
            .topnav .search-container button {
                float: right;
                padding: 15px 15px;
                margin-top: 8px;
                margin-right: 16px;
                background: #ddd;
                font-size: 17px;
                border: none;
                cursor: pointer;
                position: relative;
                top: -59px;
                left: 63px;
            }
        }

        .topnav .icon {
            display: none;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
            .topnav a.icon {
                float: right;
                display: block;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
            .topnav.responsive .icon {
                position: absolute;
                right: 0;
                top: 0;
            }
            .topnav.responsive a {
                float: none;
                display: block;
                text-align: left;
            }

            .topnav .search-container {
                float: left;
            }
        }

        @media (min-width: 426px) and (max-width: 600px) {
            .topnav input[type=text] {
                float: none;
                display: block;
                text-align: left;
                width: 88%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 14px;
            }
            .topnav input[type=text] {
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }
            .topnav .search-container button {
                float: right;
                padding: 15px 15px;
                margin-top: 8px;
                margin-right: 16px;
                background: #ddd;
                font-size: 17px;
                border: none;
                cursor: pointer;
                position: relative;
                top: -58px;
                left: 63px;
            }
        }
        /* =============================================================== */
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="wholeAreaIndex">

    <! –– header ––>
    <div class="header">
        Title
    </div>

    <! –– menu ––>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="search-container">
            <form action="/action_page.php">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
                <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <! –– content  ––>

    <div class="mainPanel" style="background-color:yellow;">
        Hello! This is a header.
    </div>

    <div class="mainPanel">
        Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
        Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
        Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
        Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
        Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
        Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
        Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
        Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
        Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
        Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
        Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
        Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
        Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  Hello! This is the main text of the page.  <br /><br />
    </div>

    <! –– footer ––>
    <div class="footer">
        Footer
    </div>


</div>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
            if (x.className === "topnav") {
                x.className += " responsive";
            } else {
                x.className = "topnav";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```